# How to create a dropdown menu from navigationbar (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a dropdown menu from the navigation bar. Something like this:

http://pttrns.com/320x480/screens/popovers/Readability_News-01.PNG.image

Readability is just one of the apps that does something like this.

How can i make something similar? Is that an uitableview?

Answer (score 0):

This should let you do the popover in an iphone. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover

its not exactly like that of readability, but I guess you could mess with it to make it look closer to what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this too! This is more in line with a OSX sheet. What you would do is as follows:

- create an overlay view - a clear UIView with userInteraction turned off - to prevent user from tapping elsewhere in your app (or you can use a tap in this view to dismiss the sheet. Add this view as a subview to your view or the view.window.
- create the "sheet" using another view. In the example above, it would appear to be a table view, but you can do any kind of view you want. You can set the frame of this view to have a 0 height, add it to the view (or window). then animate using a new frame with the real height to get the "sheet" to "drop down" from the top of the screen.
- This newly added view is then managed by your primary view class.
- When you want to dismiss it, you then animate the frame back to have a height of 0, remove that view from its superview, remove the overlay view from its superview, and your done!

Comment: I use the Wepopover in my app now - but its a totally different look - it looks like a miniature iPad popover.